# setting password for a form

Tags: c#, passwords

I tried to set a password for a form and made a new form with lable,textbox and ok button but when i write my password in text box it says it is incorrect while the password is correct..what is the problem?

```
public partial class Password : Form
{
    private string password;
    public Password()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void pass_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      string password = "mypass";
    }

    private void okButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (passtextBox.Text == password)
        {
            list form = new list();
            form.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Password. Try Again!!");
        }
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this is creating a local variable string.

```
private void pass_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string password = "mypass";
}
```

Instead do this.

```
private void pass_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  password = "mypass";
}
```

Comment: Thanks lol. I just happened to look at the right time.

Comment: many times the response time is insane on SO

Comment: Ya i have noticed that before.